# What is the difference between these two NGINX rewrite rules and what do they actually do?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have NGINX reverse proxy code that I've been experimenting with (through trial and error) to ultimately get the result I want.

**The below rewrite rule does what I want it to do**; however, I'm not sure if there's a better way to do it since I stumbled upon this through trial and error.  Also, I don't want any unexpected results.

```
rewrite ^/$ /web/index.html;
```

Originally, I incorrectly thought the below rewrite rule *should* do what the above rule does.. However, it does something completely different.  I would like to know what it actually does in contrast to the first rewrite rule.

```
rewrite ^/$ http://$http_host/web/index.html;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always find the best explanation inside the documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

Most important:

> If a replacement string starts with “http://”, “https://”, or “$scheme”, the processing stops and the redirect is returned to a client.

So it basically sends that url to the client and the client sends a new request to the new link. You can also see the new link inside you browser link bar.

If the redirect doesn't start with those keywords, it will just be handled internally by nginx. So it just adjust the requested uri internally to decide what it should return to the client. You can also see in the browser link bar that you are still on the link you have requested.

A minimal example would be the following:

```
location /test {
  rewrite ^/test$ http://localhost/web/index.html;   # client gets redirected
}

location /tester {
  rewrite ^/tester$ /web/index.html;   # serves the index.html on that link
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Considering: `rewrite ^/$ /web/index.html;` AND considering that when I type the URL:  `plex.mydomain.com` in the web browser address bar and press enter.  The URL then gets automatically rewritten to:  `https://plex.mydomain.com/#!/`. This is actually what I want it to do; effectively removing the string `/web/index.html` from the URL response. However, I achieved this result by a COMPLETE accident.  Anyway, the primary reason I'm asking this question on StackOverflow is to see if there's a better way to do what I want by someone that has much more experience than me.

Comment: I think you need to clarify what exactly you want. You just want the `index.html` to be served from the root `/` without the need to append it in the link? Does the html need to be served on `/web/index.html`? I think to really help you, we need at least the nginx site configuration file and maybe a tree structure or at least some explanation about the content you want to serve and where :)

Comment: Please see my previous comment.  I did my best to describe what the rewrite rule effectively does in a real-world scenario; which is my desired outcome.  It automatically changes `https://plex.mydomain.com/web/index.html/#1/` to `https://plex.mydomain.com/#1/` in a web server response.  I just need to know if there's a better way to do this considering I made it by just pure trial and error with limited experience.

Comment: So you want the content on both locations or just need it at one? And do you want the user to be redirected to `https://plex.mydomain.com/#1/` or just show the same content on `https://plex.mydomain.com/#1/` like its on `https://plex.mydomain.com/web/index.html/#1/` so it's accessible from both uris? Sorry for annoying with asking, but the question is not that precise yet.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I appreciate it.  I want it to show the same content on `https://plex.mydomain.com/#1/` like it's on `https://plex.mydomain.com/web/index.html/#1/` so it's accessable from both URI's.

Comment: PS: I would prefer it to actually show `https://plex.mydomain.com` instead of `https://plex.mydomain.com/#1/`  However, I think that's a result of the hidden Javascript code that much harder to rewrite.

Comment: I think the `rewrite` is a good option to achieve what you want. Another option would be to tell the location block to serve that `index.html` on request, but I don't think thats better. For this to work you would use something like `location =/ { root /path/to/file; index index.html; }` and that should achieve the same result. I personally don't know whats more efficient, just know the second option works without the extra nginx extension for redirect. But I think your way to handle it is fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254631/discussion-between-mkanet-and-geilmaker).